# Javascript - loop through number of times based on qty variable

Tags: javascript, loops

I have the following javascript object

```
[Object { url="http://domain.com/abc", qty="1" }, Object { url="http://myurl.com/cde", qty="2" }]
```

I want to be able to loop through the object and output the URL using console.log()  based on the qty variable.

So in this instance domain.com/abc would display once & the myurl.com/cde would display twice as the qty is set to 2.

I have something like the following but needs some work..

```
cart.forEach(function(value) {
   var qty = value.qty;
   var url = value.url;
   var i = 0;

   while ( i < qty ) {
     // logic needed here (i believe)
     i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'output the URL' ?

Comment: Sorry my fault - just console.log(url);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how one can implement String.repeat in JS:

```
var repeatedString = Array(repeatsCount + 1).join(stringToRepeat);
```

... so in your case it'll be just ...

```
console.log(Array(+value.qty + 1).join(value.url));
```

Unary plus is a shortcut for `Number(value.qty)`: it looks like you got a string there.

---

But it looks you actually need to *collect* all the urls instead. That's one possible way to do that:

```
var arrayOfUrls = [];
cart.forEach(function(value) {
   for (var i = value.qty; i--) {
     arrayOfUrls.push(value.url);
   }
});
```

Alternative (.reduce-based):

```
var arrayOfUrls = cart.reduce(function(arr, value) {
  for (var i = value.qty; i--) {
     arr.push(value.url);
  }
  return arr;
}, []);
```

Comment: I think i may have explained a bit weird... Basically each url will go into an array. So in this instance - i'd have three URL's (with two being the same). Hope that makes sense

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't make the issue clearer. What does 'go into an array' mean? Just `someArray.push(someUrl)`? If so, you can just reuse the second snippet (replacing `console.log` with `someArray.push` line).

Comment: sorry.. yeh each url would be pushed into an array.. so the final array would look like 
array('URL1', 'URL2', 'URL2')

Sorry - Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Brill - thats super stuff :)